# Azure arm intelligent provisioning

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to set a standard virtual machine template via ARM deployed on the azure portal and feel I'm missing a trick.

When deploying a virtual machine via azure you can select existing vnets and based off your selection you can select a subnet.

Via the ARM template deployment method I do not see a way other then putting all the subnets in the allowed values and hoping the end user chooses the right one.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

theres no easy way of doing this currently. [Managed Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-managed-applications/) might be of a value there, but they are not exactly arm templates. But they have some controls to allow for "smart" value picking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can generate a powershell script that queries azure dependant on selections and fill in the arm template from said selections. Just would be nice if could have built in the intelligence within ARM deployment.

Thank you for the managed applications information